# How can I solve what kind of function this is?

Tags: calculus, integration

When I have a series of equations

$\int_0^1 x^n f(x) dx = \frac{\lambda^n}{n+1},$

Where $\lambda$ is some constant with norm less than 1. How can I determine what $f(x)$ is?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to use right click >copy as >latex in mathematica

Comment: Please see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for help with mathjax formatting.  If you need a more in-depth guide, see: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

When $\lambda = 0$ we can solve it with $f(x) \equiv 0$.

When $\lambda \in (0,1]$, take

$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 / \lambda & x\in (0,\lambda] \\
0 & x\in (\lambda,1) \end{cases} $$

then your integral is the same as

$$ \int_0^\lambda x^n \frac{1}{\lambda} \mathrm{d}x = \lambda^n / (n+1) $$

Comment: @Kong, the integral from $\lambda$ to $1$ equals zero, so the integral from $0$ to $\lambda$ equals the integral from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you require $f \in L^{\infty}[0,1]$, then this is unsolvable if $\lambda > 1$, because then as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the right-hand side grows while the left hand side shrinks.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Can we solve it when lambda is smaller than 1?

Comment: "Left hand side shrinks" is unconvincing. I can imagine $f$ unbounded and wildly oscillating near $1$.

Comment: You're right, I was implicitly assuming here that $f \in L^{\infty}$.

Comment: You don't need $L^\infty$ even. Just $L^1$ is good enough, since $x^n$ is signed so you have that $\int x^n f(x) \mathrm{d}x \leq \int x^n |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x \to 0$.